Having issues fetching the chat for a single course
I want to get the chats that relate to different courses but when a user is enrolled for two different courses, the chats are combined . Been debugging to know what is wrong Here is my Schema
Schema::create('chat_messages', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('sender_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('receiver_id');
            $table->text('message');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('course_id')->nullable();
            
            // Define foreign key constraint without onDelete('cascade')
            $table->foreign('course_id')->references('id')->on('courses');
            $table->timestamps();

            // Define foreign key constraints
            $table->foreign('sender_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->foreign('receiver_id')->references('id')->on('users');
       });
    
$fetch_chat = DB::table('chat_messages')
        ->where('id', $id)
        ->pluck('sender_id');
    
    $fetchMessages = DB::table('chat_messages')
        ->join('courses', 'chat_messages.course_id', '=', 'courses.id')
        ->join('users as sender', 'chat_messages.sender_id', '=', 'sender.id')
        ->join('users as receiver', 'chat_messages.receiver_id', '=', 'receiver.id')
        ->where(function ($query) use ($fetch_chat) {
            $query->where('chat_messages.sender_id', Auth::id())
                ->orWhere('chat_messages.receiver_id', Auth::id());
        })
        ->where(function ($query) use ($fetch_chat) {
            $query->where('chat_messages.sender_id', $fetch_chat)
                ->orWhere('chat_messages.receiver_id', $fetch_chat);
        })
        ->select(
            'chat_messages.*',
            'sender.avatar as sender_avatar',
            'sender.name as sender_name',
            'receiver.*',
            'courses.id as course_id',
            'courses.title as course_title',
            'chat_messages.message',
            'chat_messages.created_at'
        )
        ->orderBy('chat_messages.created_at', 'asc') // Order by created_at in ascending order
        ->get();
            return view('instructor.messages.chat_viewer', compact('fetchMessages'));


@foreach($fetchMessages as $message)
                            @if($message->sender_id == Auth::id())
                                <div class="message-out">
                                    <div class="d-flex">
                                        <div class="flex-shrink-0">
                                            <div class="chat-avatar">
                                                <img class="rounded-circle img-fluid wid-40" src="{{ asset('images/auth/icons/avatars/' . Auth::user()->avatar) }}" alt="{{ Auth::user()->name }} Avatar">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="flex-grow-1 mx-3">
                                            <div class="d-flex align-items-start flex-column">
                                                <p class="mb-1 text-muted">You <small>{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($message->created_at)->format('h:i A') }}</small></p>
                                                <div class="message d-flex align-items-start flex-column">
                                                    <div class="d-flex align-items-center mb-1 chat-msg">
                                                        <div class="flex-grow-1 me-3">
                                                            <div class="msg-content bg-primary card mb-0">
                                                                <p class="mb-0">{{ $message->message }}</p>

                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            @else
                                <div class="message-in">
                                    <div class="d-flex">
                                       <div class="flex-shrink-0">
                                            <div class="chat-avatar">
                                                <img class="rounded-circle img-fluid wid-40" src="{{ asset('images/auth/icons/avatars/' . $message->sender_avatar) }}" alt="User image">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="flex-grow-1 mx-3">
                                            <div class="d-flex align-items-start flex-column">
                                                <p class="mb-1 text-muted">{{ $message->sender_name }} <small>{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($message->created_at)->format('h:i A') }}</small></p>
                                                <div class="message d-flex align-items-start flex-column">
                                                    <div class="d-flex align-items-center mb-1 chat-msg">
                                                        <div class="flex-grow-1 me-3">
                                                            <div class="msg-content card mb-0">
                                                                <p class="mb-0">{{ $message->message }}</p>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            @endif
                        @endforeach



I want to get the chats that relate to different courses but when a user is enrolled for two different courses, the chats are combined
